# got an unexpected keyword argument url

Tags: django, django-urls

I have this error since 2 days

```
TypeError at /manager/produit/detail/s/

produit_detail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'letter'
```

and I don't see the bug, can you help me?

This is my `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^manager/produit/detail/(?P<letter>\w{1})/$',
    'appli.views.produit_detail', name="produit_detail"),
```

this is views.py

> def produit_detail(request,letter):
>
> ```
>     from appli.models import Produit
>     
>     produits = Produit.objetcs.filter(nom__startswith=letter)
>
>     return render(request,'produit_detail.html')
> ```

i called the url from this template

```
<p>{% for i in l %}
                <a href="{% url 'produit_detail' i %}">{{ i }}</a>
             {% endfor %}</p>
```

Comment: You need to show us how you defined the view, at least the argument list.

Comment: How are you calling this url? I just implemented it in my project and it works without your error.

Answer (score 1):

You can only put i if you put int value. If you want to call a string you must put the variable with the value like this.

```
<p>{% for i in l %}
       Sample 1: <a href="{% url produit_detail letter=i %}">{{ i }}</a>
       Sample 2: <a href="{% url appli:produit_detail letter=i %}">{{ i }}</a>
       Sample 3: <a href="/manager/produit/detail/{{i}}">{{ i }}</a>
   {% endfor %}
</p>You did not put value for letter
```

Comment: get the quote of produit_detail.